# HTML video rewinder

Tags: html, video

I would like to ask if there is someway I can hide this rewind line from my webpage?

[image: rewind line]

I have a website with fullscreen video and I would like to disable any kind of rewinding.

My code:

```
<video autoplay="true" loop controls muted>
     <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide only the video scroller. You can hide the entire controls panel:

Just lose the `controls` attribute from your `<video>` tag:

```
<video autoplay="true" loop muted>
     <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```